# query about create has_many & belongs_to records using FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, has-many, belongs-to

I am writing Rspec `requests spec`, and before it I want to build some test data using `FactoryBot`.

And now I have a model `Game`:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :game_levels
```

and a model `GameLevel`:

```
class GameLevel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
```

In my `/spec/factories/game.rb`:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :game do
    name { :Mario }
  end
end
```

In my `spec/factories/game_level.rb`:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :game_level do
    name { :default }
    min_level { 0 }
    max_level { 100 }

    game
  end
end
```

In my `spec/requests/user_plays_game_spec.rb`, I simply wrote code to create game & game_level, and printed `game.id`, `game_level.game_id`. I found they are not the same. besides, `game.game_levels` returns `nil`.

```
before(:all) do
  @game = create(:game)
  @game_level = create(:game_level)
end

describe do
  it do
    puts @game,id, @game_level.game_id
    puts @game.game_levels

    expect(@game.id).to eql(@game_level.game_id)
  end
end
```

So how do I associate a `belongs_to` record to a `has_many` record using `FactoryBot`?

Comment: do you need to do this in your tests or in your factory definitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can associate it during the create

```
@game = create(:game)
@game_level = create(:game_level, game: @game)
```

Answer (score 1):

Associations in factories are intuitive:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :template do
    template_category { create(:template_category) }
  end
end
```

Nothing fancy. If it's not working for you you might have a config issue.